# NUnit, CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(...,...), C# Question

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm new to NUnit and looking for an explination as to why this test fails?

I get the following exception when running the test.

> NUnit.Framework.AssertionException:   Expected: equivalent to < <....ExampleClass>, <....ExampleClass> >
>     But was:  < <....ExampleClass>, <....ExampleClass> >

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class ExampleClass
{
    public ExampleClass()
    {
        Price = 0m;
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ExampleClassTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ExampleTest()
    {

        var collection1 = new Collection<ExampleClass>
               {
                     new ExampleClass
                         {Qty = 1, SKU = "971114FT031M"},
                     new ExampleClass
                         {Qty = 1, SKU = "971114FT249LV"}
                 };

        var collection2 = new Collection<ExampleClass>
               {
                     new ExampleClass
                         {Qty = 1, SKU = "971114FT031M"},
                     new ExampleClass
                         {Qty = 1, SKU = "971114FT249LV"}
                 };

        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(collection1, collection2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to determine if 2 collections are equal NUnit must eventually compare the values within the collection.  In this case the values are of type `ExampleClass` which is a `class`.  It does not implement any equality testing (such as overriding Equals and GetHashCode) so NUnit will eventually do a reference comparison.  This will fail as each collection contains different instances of `Example` even though the fields have the same values.

You could fix this by adding the following to the `ExampleClass`

```
public override bool Equals(object o) {
  var other = o as ExampleClass;
  if ( other == null ) { return false; }
  return this.Description == other.Description
    && this.SKU == other.SKU
    && this.Price == other.Price
    && this.Qty == other.Qty;
}

public override int GetHashCode() { return 1; }
```

Note: I chose the value 1 for `GetHashCode` because this is a mutable type and the only truly safe return value for GetHashCode on a mutable type is a constant.  If you intend to use this as a key in a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` though you will want to revisit this.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on your `ExampleClass`. Without that, NUnit is doing a reference equality check ("are these the exact same object?"), not a value equality one ("do these objects look alike?").

Comment: Implementing Equals solely for testing purposes may introduce Equality Pollution: http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html#Equality Pollution

Comment: I fixed the Equals override and my example test works.  So, is it just good practice to override the GetHashCode() method or is it necessary for some other reason?  Thanks!

Comment: The `GetHashCode` implementation needs to agree with `Equals`: if two objects are the same, they must have the same hash code. (Two objects can have the same hash code even if they're different, but if different objects have the same hash code, `Equals` must return false.)